# Not sure how to say "I got used to it compared to before" or something similar

Tags: grammar, translation

Not sure how to say "I got used to it compared to before" or something similar:

> 1. 前よりに慣れるようになった。
> 2. 前よりに慣れるのです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the 前よりに that appears in both of your candidate sentences doesn't make any sense. に can't attach to 前より, so the expression should be either just 前より慣れる or 前より**それに**慣れる (where それ could be replaced by more specifically whatever it is you're talking about getting used to).

Secondly, in your first candidate, the ように doesn't really fit in this expression. ～ようになる in this sense is used to express something you're doing more frequently than before, but since 慣れる refers to the *process* of becoming used to something, it doesn't make much sense to talk about doing it more frequently. It would be like saying in English "I've got into the habit of getting used to it" - it implies that you have to get used to it all over again every time. So it would make more sense to simply omit the ようになった here and say 前より慣れた.

As for your second candidate sentence, the only real problem with it (aside from the unnecessary に previously mentioned) is that it's not in the past tense -  so it doesn't mean "I've got used to it", it means "I get used to it". Again, this doesn't seem very natural since it's a habitual expression, whereas "getting used to something" is a process that usually only happens once over a period of time. If you change the sentence into the past tense (前より慣れたのです) it's perfectly acceptable.

So in conclusion, neither of your suggested sentences are perfect as-is, but they would be fine with a little adjustment, as 前より慣れた(のです). To make it sound even more natural, and perhaps include a little more of the gradual/comparative sense that I think you were trying to achieve with the ようになる, I would perhaps suggest something like 前より慣れてきた, where the きた suggests a gradual process that's still in progress.

Comment: ***Finally***, a user with a native-level understanding!